# Is there a native color picker dialog for Android?

Tags: android, color-picker

I am in need of a color picker in my Android app, where users can select any color of their choosing from a color wheel style color picker.  I have searched and cannot find a native Android color picker supplied by Google.  I've tried 4 different 3rd party color pickers and each of them has issues that make them less than ideal to use.
Is this basic feature not available for Android?  I am looking for a color picker dialog to be presented, where the initial color can be set, and the user selects the color they want.

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: Nope. The time you spent asking this question (and wait a bit for an answer) is the same time that occurs to do it by yourself........